# Graficar en 3d un lm

Tags: r

Tengo un diseño experimental factorial el cual quiero gráficar.
Yo hago:

```
LmA<-lm(z ~ (x+ I(x^2)+y+I(y^2)+I(y*x)), data=dudagrafico)
summary(LmA)
```

y así obtengo la formula del modelo.
Quisiera poder realizar un gráfico de este estilo:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí les dejo los datos:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p70wktb3klzyhbm/dudagrafico.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo buscas dibujar una superficie a partir del modelo de regresión definido. Una posibilidad es usar [`rgl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html) que ofrece un graficación interactiva muy interesante. En primer lugar, si no tienes el paquete `rgl`, deberías instalarlo: `install.packages("rgl")`. Luego veamos un ejemplo:

```
library(rgl)
library(readxl)

# Usando valores random
set.seed(700)
xyz <- as.data.frame(cbind(x=sample(1:100, 100),
                           y=sample(1:100, 100),
                           z=sample(1:100, 100)))

# Usando los datos de la planilla
xyz <- read_xlsx(path="C:/Tmp/dudagrafico.xlsx")

LmA<-lm(z ~ (x+ I(x^2)+y+I(y^2)+I(y*x)), data=xyz)

# Generamos un conjunto de puntos con todas las combinaciones
# El parámetro by establece el tamaño de la "malla" 
newdat <- expand.grid(x=seq(min(xyz$x),max(xyz$x),by=5), 
                      y=seq(min(xyz$y),max(xyz$y),by=5))

# Generamos los valores de z
newdat$z_predicted_vals <- predict(LmA,newdata=newdat)

# Dibujamos la dispersión 3d de los puntos
with(xyz,plot3d(x, y, z, col="blue", size=1, type="s"))

# Dibujamos la superficie
with(newdat,surface3d(unique(x),unique(y),z_predicted_vals,
                      alpha=0.3,front="line", back="line"))

# Para tomar una foto del gráfico
snapshot3d("prueba.jpg")
```

La generación de la superficie la hacemos combinando todos puntos `x`, `y` desde el primero hasta el último en grupos de `5`, esto último determinará el tamaño de la malla o grilla de la superficie. Luego simplemente calculamos el valor de `z` en función al modelo dado, con estos datos ya podemos crear el gráfico mediante [`plot3d()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgl/versions/0.98.22/topics/plot3d) (si no queremos mostrar los puntos hay que configurar `size=0`) y luego agregar la superficie el gráfico usando [`surface3d()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgl/versions/0.98.22/topics/surface3d)

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Patricio, muchas gracias.
¿Cómo se podría eliminar el cubo y dejar solo tres ejes (x, y, z) y eliminar la notación científica de los valores?